# Continuously update datasource from API uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a iOS application with a tableview which show a list string data from API. The data can be update continuously so I want my tableview can update datasource continuously.
This app like exchange rate board in a bank.
Anyone give me a some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need animation, you can call [`-(void)reloadDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata?language=objc) anytime when your data is updated.

```
<...>
[self updateDataSource];
[self.tableView reloadData];
<...>
```

If you need some animation you should use [other methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9):

```
<....>
[self.tableView beginUpdate];
[self updateDataSource];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:<inserted rows index paths> withRowAnimation:<animation>]; 
[self.tableView endUpdates];
<...>
```

Comment: I know reloadData or update with animation on tableview.But when datasource update continuously, tableview must be reload continuously same. I want to process for good UX.Thank you!

Comment: It is very sadly, but there is no magic in our word , we just have API and should use it to achieve goals. You can use these methods only to display new data. Also don’t forget, that a tableView creates cells only for visible rows. If you have rows with variable height, you should use estimated height property, to decrease amount of calculations.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think i will use a timer to reload tableview for resolve this.

Comment: Why don't you want to notify a tableController about new data every time? Don't forget that timer retain his target and should be added into a run loop with common mode to notify  while a user touch a screen.